# What changes during the night-time?

Tags: pixel-dungeon

I loaded up Pixel Dungeon at 12:31 AM today, and was surprised by the orange text "Be cautious, since the dungeon is even more dangerous at night!" That got me wondering. What all changes when the dungeon enters its "night-time" mode?

NOTE: I do not know if this applies to the original game, as I am playing an upgraded version called Shattered Pixel Dungeon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this page](http://pixeldungeon.wikia.com/wiki/Game_mechanics/Enemies) on the Pixel Dungeon Wiki, enemies spawn twice as often at night. There may be other risks of playing at night, but I couldn't find any. I thought in particular that vampire bats were more common at night, but the wiki entry doesn't mention this, so it might not be true.

Comment: Additional details: You also have a different ending screen (http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/pixeldungeon/images/5/52/Night_surface_crop.png/revision/latest?cb=20140615005342) and night time is defined to be between 12AM and 7AM (http://pixeldungeon.tumblr.com/post/65335504197/nighttime)